# Namespace cannot be found for installed package after building

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, fody

I'm trying to use a method interceptor so I can run a method before certain marked methods in my Xamarin app. I installed Fody from the NuGet Package Manager, then downloaded MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody.

When creating my method interceptor class, the namespaces appear and the autocomplete works:

[image]

As soon as I try to build the solution and run it on the emulator, it fails gives me these errors:

[image]

And then in my class, it says that "The type or namespace 'MethodBoundaryAspect' could not be found", even though it was fine before I tried building the app:

[image]

Where have I gone wrong here? I'm open to using other open source method interceptors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/vescon/MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody/issues/47) in the weaver. We had the same issue in our project (albeit not Xamarin, but WPF with CPS) and resolved it with the workaround from the linked issue:

Open your csproj file and change the package import from

```
<PackageReference Include="MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody" Version="1.0.66">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

to just

```
<PackageReference Include="MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody" Version="1.0.66" />
```

Comment: That was it! Note that I had to delete those lines from the corresponding `<AppName>.Android`, `<AppName>.iOS`, and `<AppName>.UWP` `.csproj` files as well